# How to add/append new loaded data in array in angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs

Here I have loaded data from angularjs as below:

```
{"mainalbums":
[{"iCategoryID":"1","vCategoryName":"Hip Hop",
"albums":
[{"iAlbumID":"23","vAlbumName":"Mychoice 1"},{"iAlbumID":"30","vAlbumName":"Mychoice 2"}],
"totalAlbumCategory":2,
"loadmore":"false",
"newpage":1},
{"iCategoryID":"3","vCategoryName":"Country",
"albums":
[{"iAlbumID":"31","vAlbumName":"Dil Dhadkne Do 1"},
{"iAlbumID":"31","vAlbumName":"Dil Dhadkne Do 2"}],
"totalAlbumCategory":1,
"loadmore":"false",
"newpage":1},
{"iCategoryID":"4","vCategoryName":"Remixes",
"albums":[
{"iAlbumID":"25","vAlbumName":"Love me thoda aur 1"},{"iAlbumID":"26","vAlbumName":"Love me thoda aur 2"},
"totalAlbumCategory":4,"loadmore":"true","newpage":1}]}
```

Here, 
**mainalbums** have **albums** which have **totalAlbumCategory, loadmore, newpage**.
I want to update second **albums** from the data. How can I do it in angularjs?

Comment: To clarify, your question is tagged PHP but your snippet above is in JavaScript/JSON. Are you hoping to modify it on the client (using browser Javascript/AngluarJS) or on the server (in PHP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all Javascript objects and [arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) - you can simply access them as such.

For example, if the object in your question was called `data`, you could get the second (index `1`) object's `albums` array using the following:

```
data.mainalbums[1].albums
```

Since `albums` is an array, you can append using the `push()` method like so:

```
data.mainalbums[1].albums.push({"iAlbumID":"31","vAlbumName":"Dil Dhadkne Do 3"});
```

**Edit:**

In your example, you don't have a category id `2`, which would currently cause you problems since you have to access categories by their array index, rather than actual id. Since your categories have IDs, you may find it easier to organise your albums by changing `mainalbums` to be an object, rather than an array.

For example, if you were to define your object like this:

```
{"mainalbums": {
  "1": {
    "iCategoryID":"1", "vCategoryName":"Hip Hop",
    "albums": [
      {"iAlbumID":"23","vAlbumName":"Mychoice 1"},
      {"iAlbumID":"30","vAlbumName":"Mychoice 2"}
    ],
    "totalAlbumCategory":2,
    "loadmore":"false",
    "newpage":1
  },
  "3": {
    "iCategoryID":"3", "vCategoryName":"Country",
    "albums": [
      {"iAlbumID":"31","vAlbumName":"Dil Dhadkne Do 1"},
      {"iAlbumID":"31","vAlbumName":"Dil Dhadkne Do 2"}
    ],
    "totalAlbumCategory":1,
    "loadmore":"false",
    "newpage":1
  },
  "4": {
    "iCategoryID":"4","vCategoryName":"Remixes",
    "albums":[
      {"iAlbumID":"25","vAlbumName":"Love me thoda aur 1"},
      {"iAlbumID":"26","vAlbumName":"Love me thoda aur 2"}
    ],
    "totalAlbumCategory":4,
    "loadmore":"true",
    "newpage":1
  }
}
```

Then you could access it using category ids like this:

```
data.mainalbums['3'].albums
```

This of course depends on whether you have control over how this object is constructed.

(Note: mainalbums is now an *object*, not an *array*, but this notation is required since we need to quote the number. JavaScript won't let you use numbers as plain variable names. However, this is still the preferred way to do things.)

Answer (score 1):

Finally,

I got answer by below (and Thank you **[Samuel-Jaeschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151676/samuel-jaeschke)**):
You also can use **concat**:

```
$http.get('store/LoadAlbums/', {'iCategoryID': iCategoryID}).then(function (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.result.mainalbums.length; i++) {
         if($scope.result.mainalbums[i].iCategoryID == iCategoryID){
            $scope.result.mainalbums[i].albums = $scope.result.mainalbums[i].albums.concat(data.data.albums);
            $scope.result.mainalbums[i].totalAlbumCategory = $scope.result.mainalbums[i].albums.concat(data.data.totalAlbumCategory);
            $scope.result.mainalbums[i].loadmore = $scope.result.mainalbums[i].albums.concat(data.data.loadmore);
            $scope.result.mainalbums[i].newpage = $scope.result.mainalbums[i].albums.concat(data.data.newpage);
        }
       } });
```

Happie!!